# When I create an Azure AD user, the calendars "allowedOnlineMeetingProviders" is empty, how do I update this?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, office365, microsoft-teams

I need a users calendar to have the property "allowedOnlineMeetingProviders" contain "teamsForBusiness". I am not able to add the calendar via the create user call (graph api) so I had to subsequently update the existing calendar but it wont let me update the property (only name seems to update). Anyone know how I can programmatically set this property?

Comment: You can change an existing event to make it available as an online meeting, by setting isOnlineMeeting to true, and onlineMeetingProvider to one of the online meeting providers supported by the parent calendar.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/outlook-calendar-online-meetings?tabs=http#update-a-meeting-to-enable-it-online

Comment: @Prasad-MSFT I made a request via my Azure subscription to Microsoft since I couldn't find a solution - there reason I couldn't find a solution is because this is expected functionality (ie. they don't support this). Sorry I should have added a comment explain that here (got it a few months ago) - I added Microsofts response below

Answer (score 0):

Its because its not expected workflow ~ Microsofts response:

Hope you are doing good.
Apologies for the delayed response, I have tried to gather more details on this behavior internally, but unfortunately since this is an existing behavior in the system i.e. by design we can say since the new user needs to have some kind of interaction with the MS teams initially.
Unfortunately, we aren't much help on this scenario from MS graph api standpoint.
We request you to provide your feedback/ideas/suggestion https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform
We regret not being helpful to you on this case since this is a known issue.
Kindly let us know if you have any queries.